# Is there something like Request Scoped in AWS Lambda with node?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

Is there a scope in AWS Lambda (with node.js) that is request safe? That can be globally visible but won't be change by another possible incoming lambda event?
For instance now I have something like this:

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    dependency.doSomething(event.info)
}

const doSomething = info => {
    anotherLib(info)
}

const anotherLib = info => {
    placeWhereIReallyNeedInfo(info)
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    global.info = event.info
    dependency.doSomething()
}

const doSomething = () => {
    anotherLib()
}

const anotherLib = () => {
    placeWhereIReallyNeedInfo(global.info)
}
```

But then another lambda event could override the `global.info` before the `anotherLib` is called. This is especially a problem when I have a lot of different files and asynchronous code and need to keep passing parameters that a function doesn't need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But then another lambda event could override the global.info before the anotherLib is called.

This is actually a non-issue in Lambda functions.  It will never happen, by design.

Only one invocation of your function is *ever* running at a time in each container.  Global scope is perfectly safe in Lambda function code.

If a function invocation is running and another one needs to start, it will always, without exception, run in an entirely different container than any other currently running function.  A container won't be reused for another invocation of the function until the first invocation is completely finished.

As your concurrency increases, new containers are automatically created.  When a container is around for a few minutes without enough traffic to justify its existence, it is automatically destroyed by the service.

This allows all kinds of things that feel a little dirty but are convenient and quite safe, like creating a global "stash" object instead of passing values around.

This makes sense when you remember that you are paying a per-n-gigabyte-milliseconds charge for each function invocation to have *exclusive* use of the container in which it is running.

Comment: Thanks! I tested it and you are right, the global variable is "safe".

Comment: @Denis, it occurs to me that there is one potential case where you could cause problems for yourself, and that is if you are setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` = `false`, which is necessary if you intentionally leave anything on the event loop between invocations, such as a persistent TCP connection to another service or forked child.  If you disable that "wait" setting, and you call the final callback, having left something outstanding, still running on the event loop, then of course it could affect you after the next invocation starts.  But otherwise, the answer is accurate.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, sadly I've arrived at a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50170772/4007383) in this thread after some research. I'd be glad if you could disprove mine with a source. I really hope you are correct.

Comment: @The_Switch Your answer is correct and the accepted answer is misinformed. Lambda functions can be rerun in the same container if you haven’t changed the code and not too much time has gone by, Lambda may reuse the previous container. You should avoid state with Lambdas as that is the key point of stateless serverless functions. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: @ericgu I said nothing here that does not agree with what you just wrote.  My answer, and the original question, are about *concurrent* invocations in the same container, and this does not happen.  The question and my answer have nothing to do with maintaining state.  It is about the safety of globally-scoped variables from race conditions related to concurrent invocations.

Comment: @TheSwitch your answer is the answer to a different question, but isn't inconsistent with what I have said, here. As I wrote above,  *"If a function invocation is running and another one needs to start, it will always, without exception, run in an entirely different container* **than any other currently running function.** (The key word here is "currently running.") *A container won't be reused for another invocation of the function until the first invocation is completely finished."*  I have never stated that containers aren't reused.  Of course they are.  But only *idle* containers are.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot any chance you can provide a source for this? It sounds reasonable to me, but I'd sleep easier if I could find some official docs that confirm this. Thanks!

Comment: @SantiagoPalladino [*"The first time you invoke your function, AWS Lambda creates an instance of the function and runs its handler method to process the event. When the function returns a response, it stays active and waits to process additional events. If you invoke the function again while the first event is being processed, Lambda initializes another instance, and the function processes the two events concurrently. As more events come in, Lambda routes them to available instances and creates new instances as needed."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html)

Comment: ...and an "instance of the function" (as used here in the docs) is the same thing that I'm calling a container.

Answer (score 2):

While looking for the same answer, I've found the following Q/A statement on AWS.

> **Q: Will AWS Lambda reuse function instances?**
>
> To improve performance, AWS Lambda may choose to retain an instance of your function and reuse it to serve a subsequent request, rather than creating a new copy. To learn more about how Lambda reuses function instances, visit our documentation. Your code should not assume that this will always happen.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

This makes me believe one instance could keep running whenever the algorithm of AWS says it should. Possibly keeping the global accessible for a next request.

**Edit:**

Test results by this tech blogger (not related to me in any way) seem to provide proof in this:
https://www.trek10.com/blog/stateless/

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532855/249933) is actually wrong in this case. AWS will re-use function instances, which means global state can be retained from one invocation to the next. See the following blog post for an example of when this was [encountered in production](https://medium.com/tensult/aws-lambda-function-issues-with-global-variables-eb5785d4b876) with an AWS lambda architecture.

You should avoid relying on any mutable global state in your lambda functions.

However, if you are interested in exploring alternatives, there is the potential to use Node's Async Hooks API in order to pass state from one asynchronous event to another, without the use of globals. I've provided [outline code for this approach in a recent blog post](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2019/03/04/lambda-global-state.html).

Comment: I'm afraid you've misinterpreted my answer, or the original question, or both.  Yes, of course Lambda reuses containers, **but not concurrently**.  A second invocation starting while the first one is still running is the topic at hand.  *"But then another lambda event could override the global.info before the anotherLib is called."*  Answer: no, this absolutely cannot happen.  Global scope is quite safe *from the beginning of one invocation until the end of that same invocation*, because until this invocation ends, no other invocation will touch this container.

Comment: Yeah like Michael answer is more what I was looking after. I was worried about change during an execution, that why I asked for **Request Scoped**. If the global object is altered after the execution it doesn't really matter for me because each call of the function only read values from it that itself wrote there.